# /usr/local/include/SFML premission denied

Tags: linux, makefile, debian, sfml

In a project using SFML, I am trying to compile my team-mate part through make. All is runing fine on his ubuntu, but all goes wrong on my debian.

I put all the includes needed by the libsfml on the /usr/local/include/ folder and all the .so of the libsfml on the /usr/local/lib/

`ls -l /usr/local/include : drw-rwSrw- 7 root User size date SFML`

I dont know if the capital S is the key of the problem, i never seen it before.
On sudo Make all works fine. But i shouldn't need to be root to compile such a project.

Any advice?

Here is the error output :

```
LibrarySFML.hpp:14:29: error: /usr/local/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp: Permission denied
LibrarySFML.hpp:15:27: error: /usr/local/include/SFML/System.hpp: Permission denied
LibrarySFML.hpp:16:27: error: /usr/local/include/SFML/Window.hpp: Permission denied
```

LibrarySFML.hpp line 14-15-16 :

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capital `S` does indeed indicate the problem.  From the coreutils ls info page:

> If the set-user-ID or set-group-ID bit is set but the
>   corresponding executable bit is not set.

That means the setgid bit is set on the directory (which forces inheritance of the group ownership and isn't interesting here), but the executable bit is not.  For directories, that is the ability to look up files in the directory.  Only root can see files in that directory, and only then because root can ignore that.  Someone set the mode of the directory to a mode that should only be used for files.

```
chmod 2775 /usr/local/include/SFML
```

should fix the problem.  (Or `755` if you want to use more traditional root-only permissions; Debian is migrating away from use of the `staff` group.)